# junit runs fine when run with gradle on command line but fails to run on eclipse as a junit test

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, gradle, jmockit

junit runs fine when run with gradle on command line but fails to run on eclipse as a junit test. Why??
All tests pass with command: gradlew clean test on commandline but fail on eclipse when RunAs -> Junit

I am using jmockit as mocking framework in the test that is failing (only from eclipse). Also using, jmockit-coverage for test coverage.
Here is the stacktrace:

```
Class not found app.services.storage.daos.LoggedInUserDaoTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.services.storage.daos.LoggedInUserDaoTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at      org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
at  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
```

Comment: You executed 'gradle clean eclipse'  and refreshed your eclipse workspace ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, are there general issues which can be looked into? How to execute 'gradle clean eclipse' @AmitParashar?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `bin` and `build` folders in your project. Than refresh project in Eclipse (F5)